# Issue - Cannot open server requested by the login. The login fails when connecting to Azure SQL database with Python

Tags: python, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I am using Python to query Azure SQL database. I tried connecting using SSMS 2018 and it works. Also, I have ODBC 17, 18 drivers installed. But when I try from code, it gives:

> cannot open server requested by the login

The credentials are correct. Below is my code. please assist.

```
import pyodbc
with pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:****-dev.database.windows.net,1433;Database=****SQLdb;Uid=****@abc.com;Pwd=****;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;') as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("select * from [dbo].Test")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        while row:
            print (str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
            row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: Hi, this error is mostly seen when the firewall is not set. Have added the client IP in Azure SQL?

Comment: @NiharikaMoola-MT Yes, I do see client IP address has been set in Firebase settings for Azure SQL server.

Comment: I updated Uid value to include server name i.e. ****@abc.com@****-dev.database.windows.net. Now, I am getting "Login failed for ****@abc.com".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full code that worked:

```
import pyodbc

#Variables
driver='{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}'
server = 'xxxxxxx.database.windows.net'
database='sqldb-data*****1'

#Inserting JSON data into SQL database
def insertToSQL(jsonData):
    with pyodbc.connect('Driver={};Server=tcp:{},1433;Database={};trusted_connection=yes'.format(driver,server,database)) as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            for item in jsonData:
                sql = """INSERT INTO [dbo].test 
                        VALUES ('{}','{}')""".format(item['EMPL_NO'],
                        item['EMPL_NAME'])
    print('Insert completed')

#Read text file with comma delimiter
def readTextFile(filePath):
    data = []
    with open(filePath, 'r') as file:
        headers = (file.readline().strip()).split(',')
        for line in file:
            fields = line.split(',')
            data.append({
                headers[0]: fields[0].strip(),
                headers[1]: fields[1].strip()
            })
    print('Reading file completed')
    return data

fileData = readTextFile(r'\\abcd\*****\test.txt')
#print(fileData)
insertToSQL(fileData)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your SQL Database server is called `myazureserver` and your login is `user@example.com`, then you must supply your login as `user@example.com@myazureserver`.

Reference: [USING EMAIL ADDRESSES AS LOGIN USERNAMES ON AZURE SQL]
(https://stegriff.co.uk/upblog/using-email-addresses-as-login-usernames-on-azure-sql/)